# Need references for the strong maximum principle used in the proof of Cheeger-Gromoll splitting theorem for subharmonic functions.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, weak-derivatives

Recently, I'm reading *Geometric Analysis* by Peter Li. The proof of the Cheeger-Gromoll splitting theorem in his book(Theorem 4.4) is more simple than the one on Peterson's book, which avoid the application of smooth support functions, but I don't think it is rigorous enough, so I want some help. For your reference, the book can be found at https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/geometric-analysis/D0A2375D56122B91A0BA370530978248

The Laplacian comparison theorem in Peter Li's book states the conclusion in the sense of distributions and Peterson's book states the Laplacian comparison in the sense of smooth support functions. Peterson's book proves the strong maximum principle for subharmonic functions rigorously but Peter Li's book applies the strong maximum principle in Theorem 4.4 without any explanation. So I'm wondering if we can derive from $\int_M f \Delta \phi \geq 0$ for all $\phi\in C^\infty_c(M)$, $\phi \geq 0$ that
$\Delta f \geq 0$ in the sense of smooth support functions (the definition is on Peterson's book, Page 281), that is,

1. $f_\varepsilon(p) = f(p)$.
2. $f_\varepsilon(x) \leq f(x)$ in some neighborhood of $p$.
3. $\Delta f_\varepsilon(p) \geq -\varepsilon$.

If this implication is false, what kind of strong maximum principle does Peter Li apply? Can anyone give some references for this.

Comment: It's the Cheeger-Gromoll splitting theorem, not Gromov. The maximum principle used is due to Calabi. I suggest looking at Cheeger-Gromoll's original paper and Calabi's paper, which is cited. The paper by Eschenburg and Heintze is also good (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01876506).

Comment: Thanks @Deane. I find that Calabi uses the notion of support function s to state the strong maximum principle while Cheeger-Gromoll uses a different one. Calabi's version is the same as the one in Peterson's book, which I can understand the proof. However, I am still wondering whether the proof on Peter Li's book is correct. I don't think he is just omitting details since he explicitly states the Laplacian comparison theorem in the sense of distributions instead of in the sense of support functions. So it seems he didn't want us to apply the support function version of Laplacian comparison.

Comment: Looking at your question more carefully, I also don't see immediately how to fill in the details of Li's proof. I'm sure there's a way to do it, but it might be more trouble than it's worth. I suggest staying with the standard proof, which is pretty straightforward. It's probably not worth devoting too much effort to this now. If, later, you want to use Li's approach to prove something, you can take another look then.

Comment: After carefully examining Cheeger-Gromoll's original paper as @Deane suggested, I reformulated the question into a simple one (posted below) that only need an example of compactly supported function with specific assumptions. I'm wondering if this is a well-known fact or do you have some suggestion about constructing such an example?

Comment: I have edited my answer again. It seems that the version of Peter Li , the distributional version, can imply the strong maximum principle by deriving the version of Cheeger-Gromoll as my answer below states, using approximation. I would appreciate it if you can examine whether my answer is correct. @Deane

Answer (score 0):

Here is my latest thinking. I thought it can be solved as follows.

In Cheeger-Gromoll's original proof, they use the following definition of subhamonicity.
Here, we say a continuous function $f$ is subharmonic if given any connected compact region $D$ in $M$ with smooth boundary $\partial D$,
one has $f \leq h$ on $D$,
where $h$ is the continuous function on $D$
which is harmonic on $Int D$ with $h|_{\partial D} = f|_{\partial D}$.

This definition obviously implies the strong maximum principle as follows.
If $f$ attains its maximum in the interior of $M$, namely, at $x_0\in M$.
By the maximum principle for harmonic functions,
$h_D \leq 0$.
However, $0 = f(x_0) \leq h_D(x_0) \leq 0$.
By the strong maximum principle of harmonic functions,
$h_D \equiv 0$ and hence $f \equiv 0$ on $M$
by the arbitrariness of $D$.

So now the question can be reformulated as below.
**Given any point $x$, can we find a neighborhood $D$ of $x$ and
a specific function $\phi_0\in C^\infty_c(D)$ such that
$\Delta \phi_0 \leq 0$, $\phi_0 \geq 0$ on $D$ and $\phi_0(x) > 0$ ?** And by density of $C_c^\infty$ in $H^2_0$, it suffices to find such a $\phi_0 \in C^2_0$ satisfying those conditions.

If so, then we can derive that $f$ is subharmonic if
$\int_M f \Delta \phi \geq 0$ for all $\phi\in C^\infty_c(M), \phi \geq 0$.

The bolded question is true when $M$ is Euclidean since we can take
$\phi = R^2 - |x-x_0|^2$ and $D = B_(x_0, R)$.
And I think it is also true for Riemannian manifold since if we take normal coordinates centered at $x_0$ and we still let $\phi = R^2 - |x-x_0|^2$, then $\Delta_{Euclidean}\phi = -2n$ on $D$, and since $g_{ij}(x_0) = \delta_{ij}(x_0)$ and by continuity, $\Delta_g \phi \leq 0$ for sufficiently small $R$, so this is the desired function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oops, this answer is incorrect. $\phi = R^2 - |x-x_0|^2$ is not in $H_0^2$. Disappointed.